# why error: arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step

Tags: r

The following code was executed:

```
tb   <- tibble(
               year   <- rep(2001:2020,10)
)

tb %<>% arrange(year) %>%
    mutate(
        id   <-  rep(1:10,20),
        r1   <- rnorm(200,0,1),
        r2   <- rnorm(200,1,1),
        r3   <-  rnorm(200,2,1)
  )
```

Then the error message popped up:

> 

Error: arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step.
x Could not create a temporary column for `..1`.
ℹ `..1` is `year`.

> 

Can anyone shed light on what the reason is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It looks like a variable assignation issue. Try replacing `<-` by `=` and `%<>%` by `%>%`. Here a possible solution:

```
#Data
tb   <- tibble(
  year   = rep(2001:2020,10)
)
#Code
tb %>% arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(
    id   =  rep(1:10,20),
    r1   = rnorm(200,0,1),
    r2   = rnorm(200,1,1),
    r3   =  rnorm(200,2,1)
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 200 x 5
    year    id     r1     r2     r3
   <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  2001     1  1.10   1.62   2.92 
 2  2001     2  0.144  1.18   1.08 
 3  2001     3 -0.118  2.32   3.15 
 4  2001     4 -0.912  0.701  1.36 
 5  2001     5 -1.44  -0.648  1.11 
 6  2001     6 -0.797  1.95  -0.333
 7  2001     7  1.25  -0.113  1.85 
 8  2001     8  0.772  1.62   2.32 
 9  2001     9 -0.220  1.51   1.29 
10  2001    10 -0.425  1.37   3.24 
# ... with 190 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks! I never realized there is any difference between ```<-``` and  ```=```

Comment: @tobinz Yes it is, `<-` is used for assignation of values to global environment. `=` can also be used for that but it works perfectly inside structures as dataframes like those you are using. So errors you bet can be due to the fact that the new variables were created as objects in global environment instead of being created inside the dataframe object.